# Text Only Facebook reader?

Tags: facebook

Is there a way I can read Facebook updates, see events, and view profiles in a text only sans JavaScript format?  This is because I often surf using [CHAP Links](https://github.com/almende/chap-links-library) and Facebook is unusable in that tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. There use to be a Facebook lite version but that has been discontinued. Your best bet would be the mobile version at http://m.facebook.com.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://m.facebook.com (mostly links thats what I used on my crappy phone) or http://0.facebook.com (this one only works in certain countries though) Thats the best you can get I think.

Comment: http://0.facebook.com is certain mobile carriers.  http://m.facebook.com seems to work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an RSS reader. I use google reader to follow all my facebook stuff. http://www.kristi-barrow.com/facebook-rss-feeds-what-is-available/